# Building Cyanogenmod from source - recipe for target failed (libnativehelper.so)

Tags: android-source, cyanogenmod

I'm getting the following error about an hour into my build of Cyanogenmod 12.1 for [hlte](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_hlte), using the latest repo checkout. I am using Debian testing, have all dependencies installed as listed in [Google's build guide](https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html#installing-required-packages-ubuntu-1404) and am using OpenJDK 7. I also have all proprietary files under `vendor/samsung`. What am I missing or what direction should I look in to solve this problem?

```
...
libnativehelper/JniInvocation.cpp:165: error: unsupported reloc 43
libnativehelper/JniInvocation.cpp:165: error: unsupported reloc 43
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
build/core/host_shared_library_internal.mk:44: recipe for target '/home/james/android/cm/out/host/linux-x86/obj32/lib/libnativehelper.so' failed
make: *** [/home/james/android/cm/out/host/linux-x86/obj32/lib/libnativehelper.so] Error 1
```

Comment: This [Gerrit discussion](http://review.cyanogenmod.org/#/c/120824/) has some info - doing `WITHOUT_HOST_CLANG=true mka` instead of just `mka` gets rid of all the `unsupported reloc` errors